# How to create a server (localhost), then proceed to post data to that url/server, then retrieve it, with it all done in Python?

Tags: python, http, server, python-requests

Does anyone know what is wrong with my code?

```
import requests
import http.server
import socketserver
import threading

PORT = 8080
Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

# creates a server at url: http://locahost:8080
def create_server():
    with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
        print("serving at port", PORT, flush=True)
        httpd.serve_forever()

try:
    thread = threading.Thread(target=create_server, args=())
    thread.start()
    r = requests.post('http://localhost:8080/get-data', data={'key': 'value'})
    b = requests.get('http://localhost:8080/get-data')
    print(b.json())
except:
    print('starting the server was unsuccessful')
```

I have an index.html for the server, and the server part seems to be working fine, but when I try to post and get data, I get an errors

```
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Mar/2020 20:51:58] code 501, message Unsupported method ('POST')
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Mar/2020 20:51:58] "POST /get-data HTTP/1.1" 501 -
```

and

```
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Mar/2020 20:52:00] code 404, message File not found
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Mar/2020 20:52:00] "GET /get-data HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Edit: I figured it out, check my solution in comments

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:

```
import requests
import threading
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
import json

# 8000 doesn't mean anything, feel free to change to any other 4 digit number
PORT = 8000


# if you haven't seen this syntax before, it's Python's inheritance,
# and in this case it means MyHandler extends BaseHTTPRequestHandler
class MyHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def _set_headers(self):
        self.send_response(200)  # 200 stands for request succeeded
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")  # informs requests of the Media type
        self.end_headers()

    # entering the localhost url into your browser, you will get an additional /favicon.ico path,
    # so take this into account with testing.
    # this method is where
    def do_GET(self):
        self._set_headers()
        print(self.path)  # if url is localhost:8000/test, self.path would equal '/test'
        if self.path == '/hello-there':
            json_string = json.dumps({'hello': 'back', 'received': 'ok'})  # converts dictionary to a JSON string
            self.wfile.write(json_string.encode(encoding='utf_8'))  # like before, encode to avoid TypeError
            # the above line is what actually sends data back to client on a request for data


def run(server_class=HTTPServer, handler_class=MyHandler, addr="localhost", port=PORT):
    server_address = (addr, port)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
    print(f"Starting httpd server on {addr}:{port}")  # f before string allows special formatting
    httpd.serve_forever()


# the next line basically checks if your configurations set this file as the "main" file,
# and if so, run the following code.
# if this code is imported into another project, that means the following code won't run,
# because this file is not the main file.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    thread = threading.Thread(target=run)
    # if threading isn't used, all code after serve_forever() (line 43) would not run
    thread.start()
    url = f'http://localhost:{PORT}/hello-there'
    request = requests.get(url)
    print(request.json())
```